# Regex character limit with specified numbers

Tags: regex

I want to accept a number if it is length of 7, 9 or 10. Is there any short version of it ?

I can limit max and min length like below , but is there any way to make this range fixed by specified numbers.

```
[\d]{7,10}$
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you can get rid of the `[]` but that's about as short as it gets.

```
^(\d{7}|\d{9}|\d{10})$
```

Alternatively you could do this which does save a few characters but I think the first one is easier to read:

```
^\d{7}(\d{2,3})?$
```

Comment: You also need something at the beginning to match (beginning of the string/line, or a non-digit character). Otherwise 8 digits will be matched as well. `/(\d{7}|\d{9}|\d{10})$/.test('01234567')` returns true (JavaScript).